# LEFT JOIN confusion -- I need to retrieve a student count

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have four tables:

```
students
classes
teachers
teacher_assignments
```

`classes` and `teachers` has a many-to-many relationship and so `teacher_assignments` acts as the `xref` table (with fields `teacher_id` and `class_id`).

Each student in `students` has a `class_id` (many-to-one -- many students to one class).

*I should also mention that `teacher_assignments` has an `active` column (BOOL) which indicates whether that assignment is currently active*

---

### What I want to do:

I want to retrieve the following:

- `class_name` -- a concat of its level and sub_level, e.g. `3` and `A`
- `teacher_names` -- the names of the teachers currently assigned to that class
- `student_count` -- a count of the students in each class

At first, I tried retrieving just the `class_name` and `teacher_names`, like so:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(CONVERT(classes.level, CHAR(8)), classes.sub_level) AS class_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teachers.name SEPARATOR ',') AS teacher_names

FROM
    teacher_assignments
        LEFT JOIN teachers
            ON teachers.id = teacher_assignments.teacher_id
            AND teacher_assignments.active = TRUE
        LEFT JOIN classes
            ON classes.id = teacher_assignments.class_id

GROUP BY classes.id
```

This works fine and outputs:

```
 class_name | teacher_names
 --------------------------------------
 1A         | NULL
 2A         | John, Sam
 3B         | Sam, Sarah
```

(Class `1A` has no teachers currently, and so the NULL is expected)

... **BUT**, now I have no idea how to work the `student_count` into this.

---

### My question:

How exactly should the `students` table be joined with the others in the above query so I can produce a `student_count` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(c.level, CHAR(8)), c.sub_level) AS class_name,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teachers.name SEPARATOR ',') AS teacher_names,
          COUNT(s.id) AS studentCount
     FROM CLASSES c
LEFT JOIN TEACHER_ASSIGNMENTS ta ON ta.class_id = c.id
                                AND ta.active = TRUE
LEFT JOIN TEACHERS t ON t.id = ta.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN STUDENTS s ON s.class_id = c.id
 GROUP BY class_name
```

Column aliases can be referenced in the GROUP BY when using MySQL, otherwise you'd have to duplicate the logic that produces the class_name column value.  This is also the column to GROUP on, as GROUP_CONCAT and COUNT are aggregate functions.

To get zero as the count value, you might need to use:

```
   SELECT CONCAT(CONVERT(c.level, CHAR(8)), c.sub_level) AS class_name,
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teachers.name SEPARATOR ',') AS teacher_names,
          COALESCE(COUNT(s.id), 0) AS studentCount
     FROM CLASSES c
LEFT JOIN TEACHER_ASSIGNMENTS ta ON ta.class_id = c.id
                                AND ta.active = TRUE
LEFT JOIN TEACHERS t ON t.id = ta.teacher_id
LEFT JOIN STUDENTS s ON s.class_id = c.id
 GROUP BY class_name
```

Comment: This appears to work perfectly. Thank you for your help! The only change I had to make was `COUNT(s.id)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)` (before which I was getting a couple of inaccurate counts).

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking off the top of my head...

1. Join `classes` and `students` tables to get the student count...
2. Instead of doing a left join on `classes` in your above query, you will do a left join with the result from #1 (essentially an inner join between `classes` and `students` tables) that allows you to pull the student count.

Comment: @Emtucifor: Thanks for re-wording.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think I would use a join but instead would use an inline column select on student like this:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(CONVERT(classes.level, CHAR(8)), classes.sub_level) AS class_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT teachers.name SEPARATOR ',') AS teacher_names,
  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE students.class_id = classes.id ) AS student_count
FROM ...
```

Comment: A subselect will produce the same results as a LEFT JOIN, because the subselect could return NULL.  Correlated subqueries don't tend to perform well.